# iPhone AddressBook Search Using number

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, addressbook

i am able to search a contact name using phone number.But there is some issues.Like if the number in the addressbook have countrycode with the number and if i search with only the number it returns emty value.So it can not search the proper way.Here is the code snipet i have done.

```
- (ABRecordRef)findRecord:(NSString *)phnNumber
{
if (phnNumber == nil)
    return nil;



CFErrorRef error = nil;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

if (!addressBook) {
    NSLog(@"null");
} else if (error) {
  NSLog(@"error %@",error);
}
// Requests access to address book data from the user
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {});


CFArrayRef all = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);


CFIndex n = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
ABRecordRef record;

int count = 0;

for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(all, i);

    ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
    {

        CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);

        NSString *newPhoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *)phoneNumberRef;

        NSLog(@"%@",newPhoneNumber);

        if([newPhoneNumber isEqualToString:phnNumber])
        {
            record = ref;

            i=(int)n;
            count = 1;
        }
        CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
    }

}

if(count != 1)
{
    ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();

    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(phnNumber), kABHomeLabel, NULL);

    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,nil);
    CFRelease(multiPhone);
    record = newPerson;
}


return record;
}
```

and i am calling it like that for name:

```
ABRecordRef record = [self findRecord:@"Number_here"];

if(record){

    NSString *name =(__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record);

    lbCalleName.text=name;
}
```

My problem is that- Suppose i have a contact and the phone number is like `8801723432323` and i am searching with this `01723432323` and above code returns emty.Here 88 is countrycode.Also i need to work opposite too.Suppose my given number have country code and no country code in address book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
 if([newPhoneNumber isEqualToString:phnNumber])
```

with`if ([newPhoneNumber containsString:phnNumber])` 
for iOS8 and later and
         `NSRange range = [newPhoneNumber rangeOfString:phnNumber]; if (range.length != 0)` for earlier devices. `containsString:` is introduced in iOS8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[newPhoneNumber containsString:phnNumber]` instead of `[newPhoneNumber isEqualToString:phnNumber]`, but you should also change your logic because the containsString method can match multiple numbers.

Comment: u dont get my point i think.I told how to over look country code.suppose if my given number have country code and no country code in address book then what happens? i need both to work.

Comment: Try check out this two libraries:
https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS
https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber.